# Implementation of SQLite in Kotlin and Anko

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, anko

I have created my application database like below. I want to insert record now and retrieve as this link says https://antonioleiva.com/databases-anko-kotlin/ to use `database.use`

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.*


class AppDbHelpler : ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(AppApplication.instance(), AppDbHelpler.DB_NAME, null, AppDbHelpler.DB_VERSION) {

    companion object {
        val DB_NAME = "person.db"
        val DB_VERSION = 1
        val instance by lazy { AppDbHelpler() }
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db!!.createTable(PersonTable.Name, true,
                Pair(PersonTable.ID, INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT),
                Pair(PersonTable.PersonName, TEXT),
                Pair(PersonTable.Domain, TEXT),
                Pair(PersonTable.MobileNumber, REAL))
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db!!.dropTable(PersonTable.Name, true)
        onCreate(db)
    }
}

// Access property for Context
val Context.database: AppDbHelpler
get() = AppDbHelpler()
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    insertPerson()
}


fun insertPerson() {
    database.use {

    }
}
```

Can anyone hint me what line is for `val Context.database: AppDbHelpler
get() = AppDbHelpler()`. What it does ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val Context.database` is a usage of [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) in Kotlin. They allow for the value `database` to be accessed whenever you are in a class (or another function) using `Context`.

The `get()` method below defines the [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) of that variable. It is equivalent to a `getDatabase()` method in Java, where it will return the AppDbHelper as shown. Having it this way allows you to retrieve the helper using the variable syntax. Since the getter is a function, it will create a new helper each time, rather than how an actual variable will behave with just one assignment. Also note that since this is a `val`, a set method is not supplied.

The code is equivalent to

```
public static AppDbHelper getDatabase(Context context) {
    return new AppDbHelper();
}
```

in Java

Comment: `Extensions`- Does it allows you to make variables accessible from anywhere, depends on before dot type. If it is `Context` then it allows to call this method where you have `Context`. If I specify `X` then it will allow me to call this where I have `X` available. Is this how it works ?

Comment: In this particular case, if you are in an Activity (which extends context), you can directly write `database` to use it. If you are in a View, you cannot directly use it. But you can call `context.database`. Note that `context` in Views directly refer to `getContext()`. If you are familiar with the `with` or `apply` methods in Kotlin, you can use `context.apply{ database }` to get it. Extensions allow you to use the methods/variables as if it were part of the original class. But in the end it is called statically so you are not creating a custom class.